# How to make a class operate with math operation in java?

Tags: java, math

for example

```
myClass x = new myClass(5);
myClass y = new myClass(2);
System.out.println(x+y);
```

Output:

```
7
```

the same in Number classes

Comment: it's quite easy: you can't

Comment: "the same in Number classes" actually, `Number` doesn't support this either. It's only classes with auto-unboxing that support numeric addition (e.g. `Integer` does; `BigDecimal` doesn't).